# Simple Question about Numeric Operations

Tags: java

I have a question that may be easily answered, but the answer evades me.  In regards to numeric operations, how come when I code this:

```
double celsius = 30;
double fahrenheit = (celsius + 32.0) / (5/9);
```

I get an answer:

```
fahrenheit = infinity;
```

But, when I code this:

```
double fahrenheit = (celsius + 32.0) / (5.0/9);  // with a decimal place after 5 or 9
```

The answer comes out correctly as 111.6?

Shouldn't the (5/9) automatically become a `double` without the decimal, or am I incorrect?

Comment: This site is for reviewing working code to make it better. If you don't understand why your code does what it does, you should try to debug it (hint: what is the result of `5/9`?) or ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Division by zero gets you infinity.

Note that (5/9) is an int expression, and resolves to int 0!

To fix things, make your literals doubles :

```
double celsius = 30d;
double fahrenheit = (celsius + 32.0d) / (5d/9d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Shouldn't the (5/9) automatically become a double without the decimal, or am I incorrect?
```

I think you want an answer to `Doesn't` instead of `shouldn't`. No it doesn't become that.

Simply stated `int` divided by an `int` can only give an `int`. So `5/9` becomes 0 point something which needs to be truncated to make it an integer. Hence `0`.